# How to get fully qualified host name in Python?

Tags: python, hostname

I am trying to get the hostname in Python. In linux, if I type `hostname` on the command prompt I get

```
root@phxdbx45:/home/david/zkpython# hostname
phxdbx45
```

But if I type `hostname -f` then I get below full qualified hostname in ubuntu and that's what I need from Python as well.

```
root@phxdbx45:/home/david/zkpython# hostname -f
phxdbx45.phx.host.com
```

I know in Python we can use below code but it does not give me fully qualified host name. It gives me the output of `hostname` as I mentioned above.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
print hostname
```

Is there any way to get fully qualified hostname in Python which is reliable and correct?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the descriptively-named function [`socket.getfqdn()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn):

```
>>> import socket   
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'phxdbx45.phx.host.com'
```

Comment: That just gives me 'localhost'

Comment: I get the simple name of my machine, without the domain name, but it's the same as what `hostname -f` returns. However, `hostname --all-fqdns` returns the FQDN.

Comment: This definitely depends on how the host OS was configured. as @xApple mentioned, it's possible to get only `localhost` .